Foundry test reverting
This test is reverting after the last bet is placed:
function testGetTopThreeBetters() public {
        console.log("testGetTopThreeBettters is initialized");
        // Arrange
        vm.startPrank(USER1);
        frenBet.placeBets(TEST_GROUP_ID, THREE_MATCH_IDS, PREDICTED_OUTCOMES_12X);
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.startPrank(USER2);
        frenBet.placeBets(TEST_GROUP_ID, THREE_MATCH_IDS, PREDICTED_OUTCOMES_XX1);
        vm.stopPrank();
        vm.startPrank(USER3);
        frenBet.placeBets(TEST_GROUP_ID, THREE_MATCH_IDS, PREDICTED_OUTCOMES_1X1);
        vm.stopPrank();
        groups.addToBetterScoresMapping(TEST_GROUP_ID, USER1, 1);
        console.log("First better score added to mapping");
        groups.addToBetterScoresMapping(TEST_GROUP_ID, USER2, 2);
        groups.addToBetterScoresMapping(TEST_GROUP_ID, USER3, 3);
        address[3] memory expectedBetters = [USER3, USER2, USER1];
        uint8[3] memory expectedScores = [3, 2, 1];

        // Act
        (address[3] memory topThreeBetters, uint256[3] memory topThreeScores) = groups.getTopThreeBetters(TEST_GROUP_ID);

        // Assert
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < topThreeBetters.length; i++) {
            assertEq(topThreeBetters[i], expectedBetters[i]);
            assertEq(topThreeScores[i], expectedScores[i]);
        }
    }

Which is strange to me since the test function for addToBetterScoresMapping is passing, the function looks like this.
function addToBetterScoresMapping(uint256 groupId, address better, uint256 score) public {
        Group storage group = groups[groupId];
        if (group.betterScores[better] == 0) {
            group.betters.push(better);
        }
        group.betterScores[better] = score;
    }

Does anyone know why this might be?
The complete code is here:
https://github.com/KristofferGW/FrenBet/tree/settleBets
Here is the error:
Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/FrenBet.t.sol:FrenBetTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testGetTopThreeBetters() (gas: 3332580)

Can you share the error message you are getting when the test fails?

Hi Rohan! I added the error message to post above. Let me know if you want me to share anything else!

thank you! Could you also run the test with the -vvv flag? This will reveal exactly where the revert is happening and might make it easier to debug. You can read more about Foundry's test traces here: https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/traces

It's reverting because you haven't instantiated the groups contract instance that you're using to call groups.addToBetterScoresMapping.
You can do the same by adding this line to your setUp() function:
groups = new Groups();


This worked. Thanks a lot!

You’re welcome. Happy coding!
